# Generating a valid JWT

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver3, identityserver4

I've been getting into using Identity Server 4 this weekend, and I've mostly been impressed with the ease and it feels like I've gotten a good grip for the procedure for creating an access_token. Been using both Implicit- and ResourceOwner-Flow for creating tokens.

My problem is that my identityserver3 wep api is unable to validate the JWT created, it also fails when I'm using jwt.io for manual validation.

Example token:

> eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNyc2Etc2hhMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiRkRFQUE5NTBDRjczODM0MzEwNTZBNzY3Mjc1RTNEMzE5N0VERDJGOSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYmYiOjE0NjMzNDM2MjgsImV4cCI6MTQ2MzM0NzIyOCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImJyZnBvcnRhbF9hcGkiLCJzY29wZSI6ImJyZnBvcnRhbGJhY2tlbmQiLCJzdWIiOiIyIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNDYzMzQzNjI4LCJpZHAiOiJpZHNydiIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsImJyZklkIjowLCJhcHROYnIiOiIwIiwiYW1yIjpbInBhc3N3b3JkIl19.iUvP7jVYSZPXozF0htLbaRrl_iqz_JOIczU5WpIoA5RHfgY17YGN4ERm-8NNPvXQBgJDe2ZeCpLV3MJR4smSOxNOBlzWWlgGApl5VauE62L0POxUnwzRFt2OYh5MVcilz0hRaKstB02EPXy-rDmgsNY8u_iT0bPU8bDD0XTETPy7QRldSMNKfUmeMOC0y8RQYypmXlZsO89HlseyfqE4kptruAho_EIp61qQ3CchJrkXwSB9YBWz4PrJHAiEA_ntzskOQ7K_96jQYZDH2NxaIQRKz7RPZWQreZHtnM7tUG6PNYI02raUFF7w8SQFTjjKUBQROcPezKZMtgFiv-c2Ww

One issue I see is that according to my understanding the web api will check

> `http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks`

for the public key in the public key. The public key is as far as I can see available in the "x5c"-field, but when I use it for validation on jwt.io it doesn't work.

```
"keys": [
  {
    "kty": "RSA",
    "use": "sig",
    "kid": "_eqpUM9zg0MQVqdnJ149MZft0vk",
    "x5t": "_eqpUM9zg0MQVqdnJ149MZft0vk",
    "x5c": [
      "MIIDFTCC..."
    ]
  }
]
```

> FDEAA950CF7383431056A767275E3D3197EDD2F9

is my certificate thumbprint, which is the same as the "kid"-field of my JWT. But shouldn't the "kid"-field of the jwks response be the same, there

This is my code in the identityserver:

Setup identityserver4 with InMemory-configuration for Clients, Scopes and Users. This does seem to be working, as in getting JWTs with correct data in them.

```
        var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                   X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                   "FDEAA950CF7383431056A767275E3D3197EDD2F9",
                                   false);

        if (certCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            var cert = certCollection[0];

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.SigningCertificate = cert;
                options.RequireSsl = true;
            });

            builder.AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get());
            builder.AddInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());
            builder.AddInMemoryUsers(Users.Get());
        }
```

I'm not adding my Clients, Scopes and Users classes here, because I don't think the issue lies there.

Here is my code in the Web API using IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation:

```
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "testscope" }
        });
```

I can see my API accessing the identity server from the logs, but still after trying to find an issue in my process I keep getting "Authorization has been denied for this request." for every request.

Comment: Still don't know what caused the problem, but after updating to ASP.Net Core RC2 on both identity server and API, it now works.

Comment: I have the same issue after I upgraded the API project to ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM. I haven't touched the IdentityServer as it's not maintained by me. Did you get an answer why kid in jwks and in jwt are different or should they even be the same?